# How to find the number of squares in this figure using combination theory?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to use the same combination method shown in this solution here -

[How to find the number of triangles in this figure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587204/how-to-find-the-number-of-triangles-in-this-figure)

However, if I am trying to  apply the same logic here.

the number of straight line segements are 10 so the answer should be 10C4 but I know that is not correct. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Count the number of 1x1, 2x2, 3x3 and 4x4 squares

Comment: The number of line segments are not 10 and any 4 line segments will not form a square

Comment: I am not looking for literally counting the squares. I am looking for lazy way to count the number of squares in this figure. Also, I am not looking to mug up any formula but to understand it.

Comment: By 'count' i don't mean count all the squares one by one. Divide up the problem to finding the number of 1x1 squares, 2x2, 3x3 and 4x4 squares and you will see the pattern.

Comment: You will see that they follow the pattern $n^2 + (n-1)^2 + \dots + 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the triangle problem, not all sets of four lines make a square, so $10 \choose 4$ is not correct.  Here you need to choose two of the five horizontal lines, then choose two of the five vertical lines.  This gives a rectangle, of which there are ${5 \choose 2}^2=100$  For a square, you need to make sure the vertical and horizontal spacing is the same.  I would do it by cases.  There are $4$ ways to choose a pair with spacing $1$, $3$ ways with spacing $2$, and so on, so the number of squares is $4\cdot 4+3\cdot 3+2\cdot 2+1\cdot 1=30$

Comment: could you please elaborate this one -"There are 4 ways to choose a pair with spacing 1, 3 ways with spacing 2, and so on, so the number of squares is " I didn't understand this statement.

Comment: If you want two horizontal lines one unit apart, the top one can be any of the five lines except the bottom.  Once you choose the top, the bottom is determined.  If you want the lines three units apart, there are only two choices, start with the top line or the one below.