# How many triangles in this picture?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to apply combinatorics to find out the number of triangles in this picture.
[image]

So, first I am trying to find out the number of segments.
Is number of segments 6 here?
So, is the answer is 6C3?
But, I can see only 8 triangles. what am I missing here? Is number of segments wrong here? I am struggling with number of line segments.

Related: [How to find the number of triangles in this figure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587204/how-to-find-the-number-of-triangles-in-this-figure)

Comment: I also see $8$ triangles.

Comment: I can see $9$ triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Not every $3$ segments would form a triangle. For example, segment $(2,6)$, $(2,4)$ and $(3,5)$ do not form a triangle.

There are $8$ triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting @bof’s Answer:

> Your figure consists of segments of $5$ straight lines. Since a triangle is determined by the $3$ straight lines forming its sides, the number of triangles is at most $\binom53.$ Since each pair of line segments intersects and all the intersections are distinct, each set of $3$ lines determines a triangle, so the number of triangles is exactly $\binom53=10.$

Note that the number of triangles here should then be **atmost** $\binom63 = 20$. Also, note that each pair of line segments **do not intersect**, for example the segments $2-4$ and $1-5$ do not intersect.

We can tell by counting that there are $8$ triangles.

Comment: We could also note that the number of "bad" triples of lines (failing to make triangles) is $12,$ because each of the $3$ pairs of nonintersecting segments is contained in $4$ bad triples; so the number of triangles is $\binom63-12=8.$

Comment: how did you determine that there are 12 bad pairs to form triangle? Could you please elaborate on how did you find that there are 12 such bad pairs?

Answer (score 1):

In that image, any three *mutually non-parallel* segments give a triangle. There are three pairs of parallel segments, so you have to choose one from each pair. Each of the three choices has $\binom{2}{1}=2$ options. Thus there are $2^3=8$ triangles.